# How do I get a dictionary from an array in Swift 4.2

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift3

I've seen a number of similar questions, but none seem to match my use case.

I have a json file structured as follows:

```
{
    "Trains": [{
        "Car": "8",
        "Destination": "Glenmont",
        "DestinationCode": "B11",
        "DestinationName": "Glenmont",
        "Group": "1",
        "Line": "RD",
        "LocationCode": "A06",
        "LocationName": "Van Ness-UDC",
        "Min": "3"
    }, {
        "Car": "6",
        "Destination": "Shady Gr",
        "DestinationCode": "A15",
        "DestinationName": "Shady Grove",
        "Group": "2",
        "Line": "RD",
        "LocationCode": "A06",
        "LocationName": "Van Ness-UDC",
        "Min": "3"
    
    }]
}
```

I'm trying to get the dictionaries for each train. I've tried this (amongst other efforts), but I cant get my head around it. Here is my code:

```
jsonArray = [try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)] as! [String]
            
            for train in jsonArray {
                print(train["name"])
            }
```

This doesn't compile.

My jsonArray is set up as:

```
 var jsonArray = [Any]()
```

Comment: Please **read** the JSON. It's quite easy. `{}` is dictionary, `[]` is array. Therefore the root object is a dictionary (`[String:Any]`) and the value for key `Trains` is an array (`[[String:Any]]`), **not** `[Any]`. There is no `[String]` type at all in the JSON.

Comment: gaaah, I always switch them. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this answer will match your case, check below,
Don't get confused I used your JSON response in a file.

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file", ofType: "json") {
        do {
            let data1 = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: [])

            let jsonDic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data1, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]
            guard let dic = jsonDic else { return}
            if let dict = dic["Trains"] as? [[String:Any]]{
                print(dict)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error as NSError)
        }

}
```

If you want to use a decoder then use this.

```
struct Result: Decodable {
     let Trains:[transaction]
}
struct transaction: Decodable {
    let Car:String
    let Destination:String
    let DestinationCode:String
}
var result = [Result]()

 if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file", ofType: "json") {
         do {
            let data1 = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: [])
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            result = [try decoder.decode(Result.self, from: data1)]
             print(result)
         } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Feel free to say any mistake is there in my coding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did solve the problem along the lines of your answer, so I’ll mark the question as complete.